# Python - Looking for a more efficient way to renumber the keys in my dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Here is my current dictionary:

```
{0: [(1,1.0)],
1: [(132,1.0)],
2: [(2000,1.0)],
3: [(234,1.0)]}
```

Now, there are instances where I may have to drop on of these keys. Lets take 2 for example, the resulting dictionary would look like this:

```
{0: [(1,1.0)],
1: [(132,1.0)],
3: [(234,1.0)]}
```

Now, I want to renumber the keys so they are consistently increasing by 1:

```
{0: [(1,1.0)],
1: [(132,1.0)],
2: [(234,1.0)]}
```

My first thought was to loop through the dictionary and replace the keys but that doesn't seem like the most efficient path considering my actual dictionary has 2000 keys.

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: It sounds like you just need a list instead of a dictionary. Why not just use a plain `[]` list, then use the index of each element as the "key"? Then this is a non-issue.

Comment: Don't use a dictionary if all you wanted was a continuous sequence of indices, that's what lists are for! `del listobj[2]` would renumber the other indices for you automatically.

Answer (score 5):

```
D = dict(enumerate(D[x] for x in sorted(D)))
```

But please use a list. It is indexed by number and renumbers automatically:

```
>>> L = [
...    [(1,1.0)],
...    [(132,1.0)],
...    [(2000,1.0)],
...    [(234,1.0)]
... ]
>>> del L[1]
>>> print(L)
[
    [(1,1.0)],
    [(2000,1.0)],
    [(234,1.0)]
]
```

You can convert your dict to a list using `L = [D[x] for x in sorted(D)]`
And convert back to your dict format by using `D = dict(enumerate(L))`

So that can be a solution:

```
D = dict(enumerate(D[x] for x in sorted(D)))
```

But it is better to just use a list in first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> current = {0: [(1,1.0)],
...      1: [(132,1.0)],
...      3: [(234,1.0)]}

>>> new_dict = {}
>>> for i,key in enumerate(sorted(original.keys())):
...     new_dict[i] = a[key]

>>> new_dict
{0: [(1,1.0)],
 1: [(132,1.0)],
 2: [(234,1.0)]}
```

Answer (score -2):

It might be worth a try might solve your issue with [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects)

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d={0: [(1,1.0)],
1: [(132,1.0)],
3: [(234,1.0)],
-1:[(234,1.0)]} # added out of order case

od =OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))

dict(zip(range(len(od)),od.values()))
```

Output:

```
{0: [(234, 1.0)], 1: [(1, 1.0)], 2: [(132, 1.0)], 3: [(234, 1.0)]}
```

Comment: This assumes that dictionaries are *ordered*, which they are not.

Comment: And clearly they care about order: *so they are consistently increasing by 1*

Comment: @mad_ that is still not correct, because, when you create the dict, order is already lost. Converting it to a `OrderedDict` later won't help. Your code will work fine in python 3.7 because dicts are now guaranteed to have same order as created, but only if the dict is created in the code like in your example, otherwise it can fail if more keys are added to the dict out of the normal order.

Comment: No, an OrderedDict can't add ordering to a datastructure that didn't have order to begin with. See [Converting dict to OrderedDict](//stackoverflow.com/q/15711755)

Comment: It is very confusing and converts to a list then to a ordered dict then iterates generating a dict, but it works fine now. Removed my downvote. @mad_